# Need assistance: JavaScript Code

Tags: javascript, column, multiline-text-field

Code work whell before i add to code: **items[i].get_item("SITE")**

I can take ID from code, but not a column element. What have I do bad. Here is a code:

```
<input type='button' id='123' value='Pokaż rekordy' onclick="getSelectedItems();"/>
<div>
<p id="p1"></p>
</div>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function getSelectedItems()
{
var ctx = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
var myItems = '';
var i;
var siteUrl = '/sites/MCUW-IT/kostka-pilotaze/restauracje-pilotaże/';
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML="";
for (i in items){
    myItems = items[i].id;

    var targetListItem;
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += items[i].id + " "**+ items[i].get_item("SITE")**;
    window.location.href = window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash;

    updateListItem();

function updateListItem() {

    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Testowa Lista');
    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(myItems);

    oListItem.set_item('Poka_x017c_WWidoku', 'Tak');

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Item updated!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}



}
}
</script>
```

**EDITED**

It's don't work. Its don't giving me anything as return. See the code:

```
<input type='button' id='124' value='Pokaż' onclick="abc();"/>
<div>
<p id="p2"></p>
</div>
<script>
function abc() {

 getSelectedItems().then(function(items){
var i;
for (i in items){
    myItems = items[i].id;

    var targetListItem;
    document.getElementById("p2").innerHTML += items[i].id + " "+ items[i].get_item("SITE");
    window.location.href = window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash;

    updateListItem();
}
}
}
</script>
```

Comment: var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx); This will return only key i.e. ids of selected item. If you want other calumn data you have to explicitly call using that id.

Comment: but how. please write sample of code

Comment: This will help : https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92436/using-getselecteditems-to-get-a-field-value-instead-of-id

Comment: But how connect this with button and selected IDs?

Comment: Your requirement is to update column value to selected items right ?

Comment: But how to connect this with button, and yes and get from the selected item Title and rest of column.

Comment: the problem is only the code:**+ items[i].get_item("SITE")** rest works well. But how in my code get item and from Item column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var items = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx)
```

This will only return key i.e. ID of selected items. To get value of other columns of selected items you have to explicitly query it. You can refer [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92436/using-getselecteditems-to-get-a-field-value-instead-of-id)

Answering your specific query : refer below code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script>
var abc = function()
{
getSelectedItems().then(function(items){
var myItems = '';
var i;
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML="";
for (i in items){
    myItems = items[i].get_id();
    document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML += items[i].get_id() + " **"+ items[i].get_item("SITE")+"**";
    window.location.href = window.location.pathname + window.location.search + window.location.hash;
    var targetListItem;
    updateListItem(myItems);
    }
}
    )
}

function updateListItem(j) {
    var siteUrl = '/sites/MCUW-IT/kostka-pilotaze/restauracje-pilotaże/';
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Testowa Lista');
    this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(j);

    oListItem.set_item('Poka_x017c_WWidoku', 'Tak');

    oListItem.update();

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
}

function onQuerySucceeded() {

    alert('Item updated!');
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {

    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}


function getSelectedItems()
{
    var dfd = $.Deferred(function () {
       var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
       var listId = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList(); //get selected list Id
       var selectedItemIds = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(context); //get selected objects
       var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getById(listId);
       var listItems = [];
       for (idx in selectedItemIds)
       {
          var item = list.getItemById(parseInt(selectedItemIds[idx].id));
          listItems.push(item);
          context.load(item);
       }
       context.executeQueryAsync(
         function() {
            dfd.resolve(listItems);
         },
         function (sender, args) {
               dfd.reject(args.get_message());
         }
       ); 
    });
    return dfd.promise();   
}
</script>

<input id="123" onclick="abc();" type="button" value="Pokaż rekordy"/>
<div>
   <p id="p1">​​<br/></p>
</div>
```

On your button click call this abc function. Hope this helps !!

Comment: It's don't work. Please Bhaskar Dhone look for my edited button. It's no return anything.

Comment: this in addition to code function of getSelectedItems() from shared reference

Comment: Please try updated answer.

Comment: Steal doesn't work after click a button Bhaskar Done

Comment: what is the error that you are getting and where it is failing exactly

Comment: I don't get any error. Only the button not fire at all. Nothing is running after button Clicked

Comment: You have to give jquery reference in order to use differed. Tip : My solution does work. Code may not work as is as its not tested and tried. Simply manipulated in editor to your reference .  You have to debug and grab error and then rectify accordingly.

Comment: but how to debug javascript code?

Comment: I don't know how to validate this script.

Comment: Bhaskar Dhone please help. I can't manage this.

Comment: let me give me exact code. Give me some time

Comment: Updated my answer with code. Try this and let me know if this works

Comment: Thanks Bhaskar Dhone. Now it looks like working better :)

Comment: And Bhaskar Dhone how to find by caml records wchih contain site? function updateListItem(j,site) {
    var siteUrl = '/sites/MCUW-IT/kostka-pilotaze/restauracje-pilotaże/';
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Testowa Lista');
    // var collListItem = oList.getItemById(j);

    var queryString ="<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name="Connect" /><Value Type="LookupMulti">5</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>";
        var query = new SP.CamlQuery();

Comment: Bhaskar Dhone Still it don't work this solution that I was espected. Don't checked me the secound one.