# call executeQueryAsync mutliple times and add results into an array

Tags: jsom

I am trying to get the Files Urls from selected documents. I am using SPContext to make a call and then using a callback function to push results into an array then later in the code I loop through the array to access the urls so I can download the documents. However, the problem is that it downloads documents double times or triple times, depending on how many I have selected.

My questions are:

1. how can I retrieve the urls of the selected documents. Is there a better way than the one I have so far?
2. How can I download only a single copy of the document, thus avoiding double download of the same document?
3. For my understanding, how can I call executeQueryAsync multiple times and store the response in an array as I have done below? Please let me know how can I improve my code.

I am using Sharepoint 2013. Thank you for your help.

---

```
function DownloadFiles(onComplete) {
        var selectedItems = SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedItems(ctx);
        var count = selectedItems.length;
        if (count == 0) {
            alert("Please select an item from the list");
            return false;
        }
        var arrOfLinks = [];
        for (i in selectedItems) {
            var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();
            var targetList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(ctx.ListTitle);
            targetListItem = targetList.getItemById(selectedItems[i].id, 'FileLeafRef', 'ContentType', 'File', 'FileRef');

    
            clientContext.load(targetListItem);
            arrOfLinks.push(targetListItem);
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync(() => {
                onComplete(arrOfLinks);
            }, Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed));
        }
    }
    
    function myCall() {
        DownloadFiles((arrayOfLinks) => {
          for (var i = 0; i < arrayOfLinks.length; i++) {
             var url = window.location.origin + arrayOfLinks[i].get_item('FileRef');
            window.location.href = `/_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl=${url}`;
           }
        });
    }
    
    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert('Request failed. \nError: ' + args.get_message() + '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this other post. I think it will answer your question:

[Using getSelectedItems to get a field value instead of ID](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/92436/using-getselecteditems-to-get-a-field-value-instead-of-id)